# Fulltext search returning too many rows

Tags: mysql, index, full-text-search, mysql-5.1

Server: MySQL 5.1.66-0+squeeze1

**My problem:**

I have two databases with the same tables. One is for the testing environment and one for production. When I perform a MATCH AGAINST on the prodution table (let's call it `prod`), I get the correct result. When I do the same on the test table (let's call it `test`), I get thousand of results, that shouldn't match.

Things get even worse. I copied the table from the production database to the test database. Still everything fine in the table.

**My steps trying to resolve the problem:**

1. So I though it might be the table definition. I truncated the `prod` table and than inserted the data from `test` (INSERT INTO `test` SELECT * FROM `prod`). The same problem.
2. I repaired the table (even with USE_FRM), same problem
3. I dropped all indexes and added them again, same problem

**Now it is getting really strange:**

I copied the data from both tables into one table (giving the new rows new auto incremented IDs), problem solved, but duplicate rows, as expected. I than removed the rows from `prod` -> same problem!

So it must have something to do with the data. Trying to find the "broken row" I deleted 100 rows in each step, trying to find the one causing the issue. After hundreds of tries, I though, that I have found the one row. But after filling all data into the table again and deleting only this single row, the problem still exists.

So I really need you help as I have absolutely no clue what is going wrong and how I can solve the problem. At the moment it's only in the `test` table, which wouldn't be that dramatic, but it might also occur in the `prod` table in the future.

**UPDATE:**

OK, I think the real problem is, that the MATCH will return everything with a score larger than 0.2 using a query like this:

```
SELECT  MATCH(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6) AGAINST ("word1, word2") AS score
FROM    table
WHERE   MATCH(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6) AGAINST ("word1, word2")
```

In my table, the `word2` might match exactly the value of col6 and is included in col1. But the query also returns rows that does not have `word1` in any cols. Those rows have a score from approx. 0.2 to 0.6 and all rows with both words in any cols have a score from 8 and more.

So filtering this score for values greater than 1 does fix the problem. But how is the MATCH  AGAINST defined? Why does it return rows with a score lower then 1?

**UPDATE 2:**

In `prod` I only get a score for three rows (which are the ones, you should expect for the search) of approx. 7.3 and higher, all other rows get a score 0. In `test` approx. 40% of rows get a score larger than 0 but only the three positive rows get a score larger than 1.

So a possible solution would be using a query like the following (filtering scores lower than 1 out):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table
WHERE   MATCH(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6) AGAINST ("word1, word2") > 1
```

But is this really the right solution for the problem?